# Add anchor to react bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

The React Bootstrap Table documents provide [an example of how to select a row](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#select-radio).

However, I do not see any mention of how to wrap a row in an anchor tag (or a click handler), so that when a user clicks on a table row, they are then redirected to a new url.

How do I do this? Thanks!

Additionally, I see that in an `onRowSelect`, you could do a `window.location = ______`.

However, the `mode`: radio/checkbox is *required*, and that means the table will have that additional column with a radio/checkbox. Which, for this use case (just redirecting on click) feels superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woohoo! Got it! You can add the attribute `hideSelectColumn: true` and you will be able to register the click callback, and won't have that extra column of radio elements!

```
var selectRowProp = {
  mode: "radio",
  hideSelectColumn: true,
  clickToSelect: true,
  bgColor: "rgb(238, 193, 213)",
  onSelect: onRowSelect
};
```